# How to get List-views to automatically adjust height when the window is re-sized in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, height, gridsplitter

I'm having trouble getting the two ListViews to adjust their height to the containing window. I am using a GridSplitter between them. I want one ListView to shrink and one to grow when i drag the GridSplitter.

Here is the stripped down xaml code.

```
<Grid x:Name="Gridthing">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/> <!--bottom-->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView  Name="Things1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray"></GridSplitter>
            <ListView  Name="Things2" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

However in this example the bottom ListView always 150 tall regardless of what size the window is set too.

Now I can already hear a thousand voices screaming use "*" or "auto" for the the height of the bottom grid row.

However that has a worse problem. The bottom ListView now extends passed the window and has no scroll bar, rendering anything not in the window invisible.

I am looking for a way that allows the two ListViews to take up all the space in the window with a GridSplitter  in between and always displays the scroll bar.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Height="*"` should work fine. Is `Grid` direct child of `Window` or there are some controls between `Grid` and `Window` (mainly `StackPanel` or `Canvas`)?

Comment: we are using a UserControl not a window. but it is a direct child of the control.

Comment: So where is that `UserControl` placed and so on? Point still stands. Is somewhere between your `Grid` and a `Window` vertical `StackPanel` or `Canvas`?

Comment: yes the main window has a stack panel and inside is the usercontrol.

Comment: and this the reason why `Height="*"` does not work. You need to change it to some other panel that does not give its children infinite amount of space to grow

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was that my grid was in a userconrol inside a stackpannel inside the main window. I had to swap out the stackpannel for a grid in the main window and then it performed perfectly. thanks dkozl.